# No GlassFish server support in Eclipse Juno?

Tags: eclipse, glassfish

It is possible to install a variety or servers from
within Eclipse by navigating to Window -> Preferences
-> Server -> Runtime Environment -> Add...

However besides Tomcat, WebSphere, JBoss, JOnAs,
and OC4J I do not see an entry for GlassFish.

Why is this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to include Glassfish in my Eclipse Juno IDE by
installing it from Help -> Eclispe Marketplace... -> entering glassfish
in the search box and selecting "GlassFish Tools for Juno".

Still not sure what the difference is between the Eclipse MarketPlace...
link and the Install New Software... link other than the first leads
to a centralized repository and the second leads to a specific URL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Most server adapters are not maintained or distributed by eclipse.org and the included ones are being phased out. Use "Download additional server adapters link" on the same screen to find and install the adapter that you need.

[image]

Comment: I don't see a download server adapters link. Where do you see this?